# (click) event not working on Chrome over select's option - Angular 12

Tags: angular, google-chrome, click, html-select

I have a select input and I need to send as argument the index of the iterable item, so using the (change) event over the select, doesn't work for me. I mandatoryly have to use (click) event over the option tag, and it works on FF, but not works on chrome.

Code:

```
<select class="text-sm">
  <option value="" selected disabled>--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of item.opciones; let j = index" 
          value="{{ option.id }}"
          (click)="updateItemsList(i, $event, j)">
    {{ option.descripcion }}
  </option>
</select>
```

As you can see, if I use (change) over the select I couldn't send the j index, as argument in the method.

Someone knows why this happens in chrome and how to solve it?

Comment: Of course you can send the index with change event. Don't use click on option tag, this doesn't make sense

Comment: Index "j" doesn't exist on select tag, j index exists until option tag is readed. So javascript will throw an error: "j is undefined".

Anyway I need help with this, so if you have the answer for this to work, I will thank you if you can share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

With [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) you can access the index of the selected option.

Example (copy-pasted from the linked MDN site):

```js
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select')
var pElem = document.getElementById('p')

// When a new <option> is selected
selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var index = selectElem.selectedIndex;
  // Add that data to the <p>
  pElem.innerHTML = 'selectedIndex: ' + index;
})
```

```html
<p id="p">selectedIndex: 0</p>

<select id="select">
  <option selected>Option A</option>
  <option>Option B</option>
  <option>Option C</option>
  <option>Option D</option>
  <option>Option E</option>
</select>
```

Personally, I don't understand why this would be needed, since you can get just the value of the select and act based on the actual value.